# Sending variables between 2 privare subs in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 subs that look like this. But how can i pass information between them?

```
Private sub Sender()
  Dim A As String
  Dim B As String
  A = "text A"
  B = "text B"
End Sub

Private sub reciver()
  Msgbox = A
  Msgbox = B
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private sub Sender() 
 Dim A As String 
 Dim B As String 
 A = "text A" 
 B = "text B" 

 receiver(A,  B) 

End Sub 

Private sub receiver(a as String, b as String) 
 Msgbox = a
 Msgbox = b
End Sub
```

Comment: To fire up a message box take a look here.

https://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show-vbnet